# Including more than one variable in ax.set_title?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this title, where the variable `option` indicates the regional level.

```
option=3
year=2017

    ax.set_title('Household Gas Consumption, Water Heating,NUTS %.i'%option,fontdict={'fontsize':'10','fontweight':'3'})
```

How could I also add the variable `year` so the title looks like this?

```
Household Gas Consumption, Water Heating, NUTS 3, Year: 2017
```

I tried different ways but I could't make it work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'Household Gas Consumption, Water Heating,NUTS %i Year: %i' %(option , year)
```